# WebResources Embedded Resources and Javascript how to use them within another embedded resource?

Tags: c#, javascript, custom-controls, embedded-resource

I asked a similar question before but the response was pretty weak, so not sure if I worded it correctly.

I currently have a custom server control on an asp.net page. However the control uses entirely embedded JavaScript and Image resources. My assembly has all of the web resources correctly set-up and I have been using the images etc as icons sucessfully.

However now, if possible I would like to use the embedded webresource images directly in the javascript file. I have tried the following with no luck so far:

```
document.getElementById('button').src = 'WebResource("NAMESPACE.FOLDER.IMAGE.png")';
document.getElementById('button').src = '<%WebResource("NAMESPACE.FOLDER.IMAGE.png")%>';
```

I am not sure what else to try as most of my googling seems to meet a dead end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the WebResourceAttribute.PerformSubstitution Property:

[WebResourceAttribute.PerformSubstitution on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webresourceattribute.performsubstitution%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

We use it in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the project where embedded resources are defined:

[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("", "text/css", PerformSubstitution = true)]

**Edited:**

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Project.Content.Styles.css", "text/css", PerformSubstitution = true)]
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Project.Images.Sprite.png", "image/png")]
```

Content/Styles.css (embedded resource)

```
.icon {
    background-image: url(<%=WebResource("Project.Images.Sprite.png")%>);
}
```

Comment: I dont think this will work for images. I am already using perform substitution for the css files I have on the control. I'm trying to access images within an embedded javascript file that are already embedded within the project / dll.  My problem is accessing the embedded images from within the embedded javascript.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. We are accessing embedded images from an embedded CSS file so I assumed that it would work from an embedded javascript file. I've edited the answer to flesh out the example in case it helps.

Comment: I suspect this is probably right, however our custom control is so restricted on what it can actually do. I accept this as the answer.